# In which part of memory do you store model weights and intermediate values during NN inference in tflite micro?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I had a question regarding memory during inference of a tensorflow lite micro model. In the beginning, you define a `tensor_arena` global variable. What exactly is stored in this reserved space? Do you store the model weights, or the intermediate values during model inference, or both? What about the input data? I.e. when you feed some values to the network input, do these also get stored in the tensor arena?
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tensor arena is used to store inputs, outputs and intermediate values during inference. Model weights and biases are typically stored in the model itself. The model and executable code are stored in the read only portion of the binary, and the arena occupies the writable data section.

By default, memory within the arena is [planned and re-used](https://github.com/tensorflow/tflite-micro/blob/main/tensorflow/lite/micro/memory_planner/greedy_memory_planner.cc) wherever possible, since intermediate values can be overwritten outside of their lifetimes. For this reason, the arena can typically be quite a lot smaller than the sum of intermediate buffers.